# Write custom refactorings for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to write custom refactorings or code transformations for Visual Studio?

An example: I have a codebase with a billion instances of:

```
DbConnection conn = null;
conn = new DbConnection();
conn.Open();
...a number of statements using conn...
conn.Close();
conn = null;
```

I would like to transform this into:

```
using (DbConnection conn = GetConnection()){
   ...statements...
}
```

Everywhere the above pattern appears.

Edit: The above is just an example. The point is that I need to do a number of code transformations which are too complex to perform with a text-based search-replace. I wonder if I can hook into the same mechanism underlying the built-in refactorings to write my own code transformations.

Comment: I think you need a plugin such as ReSharper or perform it manually.

Comment: @Roboto: Does ReSharper allow me to define my own custom refactorings, or does it just happen to have a built-in refactoring for the example case?

Comment: There's only one tool that can do this reliably right.  The one between your ears.  Good thing it isn't actually a billion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marc said, this is more of a 'replace' thing than a refactoring. But in any case, ReSharper is an option, and if you decide to use it, you can check out [this guide](http://nesteruk.org/blog/page/ReSharper-Extensibility-Guide.aspx). Good luck!

It appears that the above link is now broken, try this [one](http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/10/writing-resharper-plugin-quick-fixes.html) instead

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, that isn't a *pure* refactor, since it changes the code in a way that significantly changes the behaviour (in particular, calling `Dispose()`). I would *hope* that either "Resharper" or "Refactor! Pro" would have a bulk "introduce using" (or similar). I've checked on "Refactor! Pro" (since that is what I use), and although it *detects* the undisposed local (at least, it does with `DbConnection conn = new SqlConnection();`), it doesn't offer an automated fix (trivial to do manually, of course). I would suggest:

- check Resharper (there is an evaluation period)
- if not, do it manually

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a macro to do this.